# Assert if variable of type []interface{} is actually []string

Tags: go

I am developing a RESTful API, and need to make sure of what user has sent.

Suppose this is the body of a POST request in JSON format:

```
{
    "request": "reset-users",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "users": ["userA","userB","userC"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `json.Unmarshal`, I read the body into this standardized struct:

```
type RequestBody struct {
    Request string `json:"request"`
    Parameters []map[string]interface{} `json:"parameters"`
}
```

So, Now, I can check the type of `requestBody.Parameters[0]["users"]` with the following type assertion switch block:

```
switch requestBody.Parameters[0]["users"].(type) {
    case []interface {}:
        //It is actually a list of some type
    default:
        //Other types
}
```

The above mentioned code works but how can I also be sure that ***a list of some type*** is a list of strings? (as opposed to a list of int or bool ...)

Comment: An `[]interface{}` cannot be a `[]string`.  These are different concrete types.  Check each element of the `[]interface{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unmarshaled into an `interface{}`, the standard library unmarshaler always uses the following:

- `map[string]interface{}` for objects
- `[]interface{}` for arrays
- `string`, `bool`, `float64`, `nil` for values

So when you get a `[]interface{}`, it is an array whose elements can be any one of the types above. You have to go through each and type assert:

```
switch v:=requestBody.Parameters[0]["users"].(type) {
    case []interface {}:
      for _,x:=range v {
         if s, ok:=x.(string); ok {
            // It is a string
         }
      }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. BTW you missed a `}` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation is clear on what types it will use](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal): "[]interface{}, for JSON arrays". It will always be `[]interface{}`, which is a concrete type, and cannot be asserted to any other type; it cannot be `[]string`, because that is a distinct type from `[]interface{}`. Each element of the `[]interface{}` could be any of the types listed in the doc, depending on what type each element of the original JSON array was.